# Create chart from table in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, charts, html-table

I have my table looking like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<CalcFactory.Models.Calculation>
<div id="exportToExcelDiv">
<table cellspacing="0" width="80%" id"detailTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Row
        </th>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Invoice amount
        </th>
        <th>
            Interest rate
        </th>
        <th>
            Interest amount
        </th>
        <th>
            Amortization
        </th>
        <th>
            Capital balance
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
@{var i = true;}
@{var rowID = 0;}
@{var cellID = 1;}
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    if (i)
    {
        <tr id="@rowID">
            <td align="center">
                @rowID
            </td>
            <td align="center">
            </td>
            <td align="center">
            </td>
            <td align="center">
            </td>
            <td align="center">
            </td>
            <td align="center">
            </td>
            <td align="center" id="startValue">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartValue)
            </td>
        </tr>
        i = false;
        rowID++;
    }
    <tr id="@rowID">
        <td align="center">
            @rowID
        </td>
        <td align="center" id="A-@cellID">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PeriodStartDate)
            - @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.PeriodEndDate)
        </td>
        <td align="center" id="B-@cellID">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceAmount)
        </td>
        <td align="center" id="C-@cellID">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InterestRate)
        </td>
        <td align="center" id="D-@cellID">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InterestAmount)
        </td>
        <td align="center" id="E-@cellID">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amortization)
        </td>
        <td align="center" id="F-@cellID">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresentValue)
        </td>
    </tr>
    rowID++;
    cellID++;
}
</table>
</div>
<div class="calcGraph">
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 400, height: 300);
}
```

I want to create a nice chart/graph that from this table. I have no idea how to bind or put the values from the table into myChart. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could try JqPlot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Microsoft Chat Control** which is a part of Dotnet Framework

It has support for 35 different chart types.

You can find many samples here :

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591

**Integration of MS charts with MVC is very easy**: Refer to this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125230/ASP-NET-MVC-Chart-Control

**hope this helps..**